# Are Pastafarians trying to undermine religious exemptions for identity photos?

Tags: religion, identity-document

Pastafarians have been successfully gaining the right to wear colanders in government identification photos such as those in driver's licenses, when they wouldn't otherwise be allowed to.

Are they doing so with the intention of trying to undermine the right of people to have religious exemptions for regulations surrounding ID photos, such as Sikh men being allowed to wear turbans or Muslim women wearing headscarves?

Comment: I'm not sure this is primarily opinion-based. Certainly a poll could be done (and may have been done).

Comment: I would interpret it to try to undermine using religion as an excuse to do anything which is normally not allowed, such as not paying taxes, racism or discrimination against gay people, as well as highlight the fact that "religion" is a highly undefined concept in general.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson are Pastafarians also against people wearing headscarves and turbans in their identity photos?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: I doubt that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm sure everyone has their own and different reasons. Reasons for doing it could range and include:

- to point out the futility of attempting to define what is or isn't a religious exception to secular laws
- to point out the silliness of caring what people wear on their head on a drivers license photo
- first amendment support: http://m.huffpost.com/us/entry/pastafarian-colander-license-photo_us_56498e42e4b08cda34897b27
- they have strong personal (if not truly religious) feelings towards pastafarism (pastafarianism?)
- just for fun. Wearing a colander is fun.

And I'm sure there are many more reasons.

Comment: There are people who actually believe in the religion. It might sound implausible, but then so does the idea of someone living inside a whale/big fish.

Comment: Pastafarianism is correct